# Flutter - Is there a way to query Firebase in SearchDelegate?

Tags: flutter

I want to query Firebase as query is entered and update buildSuggestions in the SearchDelegate class.
Is that possible in Flutter?
Thx a lot.

Comment: yes, it is possible - you can query any kind of database in `SearchDelegate`

Comment: What is the best way to do it? I tried loading the data in the constructor of the SearchDelegate class. That doesn't feel like the best way to do. Is there a way to use StreamBuilder or something? I couldn't find anything online.

Comment: if your data model provides a `Stream` (data changes over time) use `StreamBuilder`  and if it is static data returned by some `Future` then use `FutureBuilder`